# Mejorar consulta SQL para mostrar resultados

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo dos tablas las cuales uno por medio de `RIGHT JOIN` y la sentencia es la siguiente:

```
$sql= "select * from bookings RIGHT JOIN calendar ON bookings.date=calendar.day_Date GROUP by calendar.day_date";
```

Agrego una imagen con la estructura y la vista examinar de la tabla para expresar mejor la idea:

[image: Las dos tablas que tengo unidas]

Necesito que los resultados traigan todas las filas que tengan la misma fecha, sólo me trae de la tabla `bookings` la primera que encuentra si hay más de una (como se muestra en la imagen... muestra la línea que está en rojo, pero necesito en este caso que me traiga la fila 1 y 2 de `bookings` y me los muestre, ya que ambas líneas tienen la misma fecha).

Comment: Hola Joe bienvenido :) ¿qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando?

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr, MariaDB

Comment: @Flxtr es muy similar a MySql

Comment: @Joe te voy ha comentar como lo haria en **mysql**. Si tienes las dos tablas relacionada, en el **where**  colocarías una condición, que te filtrara por la fecha del **bookings** y **calendar**  ambas unida por un **or** espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para obtener los resultados que quieres debes usar la clausula WHERE como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$sql= "SELECT * 
       FROM bookings b 
       RIGHT JOIN calendar c 
               ON b.date = c.date 
       WHERE c.calendar_ID = 1";
```

Por cierto los diseño no están bien. Aun no entiendo cual es el sentido de la columna `date` en la tabla `calendar`, cuando existen funciones como [DAYWEEK](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php) para obtener el día de la semana de una fecha.

Comment: Gracias, no me resuelve el problema, creo que no expliqué bien la necesidad. Gracias por el dato de la función Dayweek no la conocía.

Answer (score 0):

Si no estoy confundido, lo que realmente quieres hacer es un inner join (el right join te incluirá también las no coincidencias como null)

Tu mismo puedes comprobarlo, esta sentencia debería devolverte lo que entiendo que deseas (con valores nulos)

`Select * from bookings right join calendario on bookings.date=calendario.date`

En tu caso, dado que no deseas valores nulos, debería ser

`Select * from bookings inner join calendario on bookings.date=calendario.date`

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que estás utilizando `RIGHT JOIN` para obtener todas las fechas de la tabla `calendar`, incluyendo las que no tengan registros relacionados en la tabla `bookings`.  Entonces, el problema es la cláusula `GROUP BY` en la que indicas que deseas que se agrupe por el campo `calendar.day_date`, por lo que solo se va a generar un registro por cada valor de dicho campo.

Me parece que en este caso, en lugar de agrupar, lo que deseas es ordenar, por lo que sugiero simplemente cambies `GROUP BY` por `ORDER BY`:

```
$sql =
    "select " .
        "* " .
    "from " .
        "bookings " .
        "RIGHT JOIN calendar ON " .
        "bookings.date=calendar.day_Date " .
    "ORDER BY " .
        "calendar.day_date";
```